# Angular Routes, Child routes work but parent route doesn't

Tags: angular

I have this application i'm doing on angular. I have a route 'projects' and this route has 3 childs routes. Before I added the child routes, the projects route was working find and loaded on my browser. However now 'projects' route wont load but it's child route's will.

This is my app-routing.module.ts file

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AboutMeComponent } from './about-me/about-me.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AutomatedGardenerComponent } from './projects/automated-gardener/automated-gardener.component';
import { BioMouseTrackerComponent } from './projects/bio-mouse-tracker/bio-mouse-tracker.component';
import { EasyBlindsComponent } from './projects/easy-blinds/easy-blinds.component';
import { ProjectsComponent } from './projects/projects.component';
import { ResumeComponent } from './resume/resume.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './shared/components/page-not-found/page-not-found.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent},
  { path: 'aboutme', component: AboutMeComponent},
  { path: 'resume', component: ResumeComponent},
  { path: 'projects', children: [
    {path: '', component: ProjectsComponent},
    {path: 'automatedgardener', component: AutomatedGardenerComponent},
    {path: 'easy-blinds', component: EasyBlindsComponent},
    {path: 'biomousetracker', component: BioMouseTrackerComponent}
  ]
},
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

and this is my app.component.html

```
<body>
  <div>

    <app-header></app-header>

    <div class="container" style="margin-top: 50px;">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>

  <app-footer></app-footer>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular routing works in mysterious ways, to fix this you can move some of the routings around to achieve what you want.

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent},
  { path: 'aboutme', component: AboutMeComponent},
  { path: 'resume', component: ResumeComponent},
  { path: '', children: [
    { path: 'projects', component: ProjectsComponent},
  ]},
  { path: 'projects', children: [
    { path: 'automatedgardener', component: AutomatedGardenerComponent},
    { path: 'easy-blinds', component: EasyBlindsComponent},
    { path: 'biomousetracker', component: BioMouseTrackerComponent}
  ]},
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
];
```

If you resolve the projects path before you go through the child paths you should resolve the correct route and end up at the correct component.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you change your routes config like the config below, your problem will be solved.

```
  const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
{ path: 'aboutme', component: AboutMeComponent},
{ path: 'resume', component: ResumeComponent},
{ path: 'projects', children: [
  {path: '', component: ProjectsComponent},
  {path: 'automatedgardener', component: AutomatedGardenerComponent},
  {path: 'easy-blinds', component: EasyBlindsComponent},
  {path: 'biomousetracker', component: BioMouseTrackerComponent}
]},
{ path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent},
{
  path: '',
  redirectTo: 'home',
  pathMatch: 'full',
```

}]

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add to component of the projects path like this with there childrens

```
{ 
  path: 'projects',
  component : ProjectsComponent
  children: [
 { path: 'automatedgardener', component: AutomatedGardenerComponent},
 { path: 'easy-blinds', component: EasyBlindsComponent},
 { path: 'biomousetracker', component: BioMouseTrackerComponent}
]},
```